# How to copy textures to other cubes

Tags: texturing, materials, shortcut

I have made a massive cube made from hundreds of smaller cubes for a wreaking ball to hit and knock down. I want the cubes to be wood textured. I have my texture on one cube but I want all 700 cubes to be the same texture, there is no way I can go through and texture every single cube. How do I take the texture from the one cube and apply it to all of the other cubes?

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the material.

1. To do this, select all the cubes.
2. Next also select the cube with the texture(be sure to do that one last). The cube with the textures should have a light orange background instead of a dark orange.
3. Finally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>->Materials.
4. To copy the UV unwrap, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>->Transfer UV maps

Done!

Comment: I did try to do this but the cubes stay the previous color that they were originally?

Comment: It's weird When I do that it changes the color of the other blocks to a solid color in the texture but not the actual texture?

Comment: @Connor Are all your cubes UV unwrapped? If only your one cube is unwrapped, you can transfer the UVs to the others with `Ctrl L` > Transfer UV maps. Note that all your cubes should have the same topology/vertex order for this to work.